# Placeholder for admin form field in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have an admin form where there is one field like this

```
$founderFieldset->addField('founder_name', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Founder Name'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'name'      => 'founder_name',
));
```

Now Magento converts this code to HTML and the result is something like

```
<input type="text" id="founder_name" name="founder_name" class="required-entry" />
```

Now how can put a **placeholder** for this field.

So I want the resulting HTML to come like this

```
<input type="text" id="founder_name" name="founder_name" class="required-entry" placeholder="Blah blah..." />
```

Comment: Answer found here  : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147462/placeholder-for-admin-form-field-in-magento

Comment: I know. I'm the one who asked it there. lol

Comment: putting the link here to redirect people over in case they found this

Comment: Oh. Alright then